# PHP PDO Wrong numbers of tokens?

Tags: php, pdo

Can someone tell me what is wrong with that statement cause I do not see any mistake?

```
    $PrevReleaseModel = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM model WHERE model_name=:model_name AND model_release:model_release");
    $PrevReleaseModel->bindParam('model_name',$model_name);
    $PrevReleaseModel->bindParam('model_release',$model_release);
    $PrevReleaseModel->execute(array('model_name'=>$model_name,'model_release'=>$model_release));
```

I am really confused.

Comment: You are missing `=` here `model_release:model_release` and you are binding the values and still sending them again?? You should use one.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This question has a problem explanation, error message (in the title) and minimal code snippet.

Comment: I do not care about a downvotes :) 
I just did not see that stupid equal sign haha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE model_name=:model_name AND model_release = :model_release
```

You missed a equal sign in the last condition.

Comment: Thank you sir I am just too tired I think :)

Comment: no problem ;) plz consider set my reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this out:-

```
 $PrevReleaseModel = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM model 
                     WHERE model_name = :model_name AND 
                     model_releas = :model_releas'
            );
$PrevReleaseModel->bindParam(':model_name', $model_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$PrevReleaseModel->bindParam(':model_releas', $model_release, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$PrevReleaseModel->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you I know how to use PDO I just didnt spot the equal sign ;)

Comment: Well that should be `$PrevReleaseModel->bindParam(':model_releas', $model_release, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: Alright, i did not know your Table structure, just edit it